# Prevent automatic basic http authentication from password stored in cache

Tags: http, browser-cache, basic-authentication

I am building a prototype jquery based ui for a RESTful backend secured with basic http authentication ,there are no sessions or session IDs .Now the username and password keeps getting cached and I am able to authenticate myself if I do not provide a username and password ,How can I prevent this behavior ?

I saw similar questions asked but mostly they have been solved by using client  side validation.Are there any other solutions to this ?

There are similar questions to this and answer is no,So the how to deal with this